# Is there any way to debug Iphone on linux or windows for javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug Iphone on linux and windows. But unfortunately after spending 2 days I am asking this question. I have tried [jsconsole.com](https://jsconsole.com/) but this is not working. Is there any way to do that currently. I have tried the debugging on windows to but the version of safari is not 6 or greater in windows, as safari allows debugging on version 6 or later. I tried to make a virtual machine too but virtual machine do not allow to connect Iphone with it. I have some errors on my website for Iphone not for windows or android. Is there any way to remotely debug Iphone on windows or linux with using remote debugger or any other way?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't. Apple really wants you to use just their devices in development. You could try to make a hackintosh though.

Comment: You can't. Just like you can't develop swift on windows. The Apple way.